# Элементы combobox прокручиваются мышкой когда уже этого не надо.

Tags: c#

После выбора элемента в **combobox** этот элемент остается выделенным синим цветом  и его можно прокручивать колесиком мыши. Это мешает. Можно ли сделать чтобы после выбора элемента в **combobBox** щелкнув на свободном пространстве выделение синим цветом исчезало и колесико мыши уже не меняло выбор элемента? или чтобы прокрутка колесиком была возможен только тогда когда список **comboBox** расправлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так: создать обработчик события на изменение выбранного элемента и в конце метода обработки события передать фокус другому контролу или форме, например

```
 Form1.Focus();
```

**UPD** Дело в том, что метод Focus() не выделяет, а передает фокус. Фокус это текущий элемент, он может быть в определенный момент времени только один.

Comment: Возникает ошибка:
Ошибка 1 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "System.Windows.Forms.Control.Focus()" требуется ссылка на объект F:\Documents and Settings\Passenger  №9\Мои документы\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Копия Копия 3.0\3.0\Form1.cs 108 13 3.0

Comment: Так Вы не у класса вызывайте метод, а у объекта.

Comment: Я понял, что можно на **lable** передать и тогда все нормально. Но в начале отладки (Debug) почему-то **Form1** загружается с одним выделенным контролом, хотя у меня в конце метода **Form1_Load** прописано  **label3.Focus();**

Answer (score 1):

Можно в обработчик события в самый конец добавить

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
.......
this.comboBox1.MouseWheel += this.comboBox1_MouseWheel;
}
```

Добавим процедуру для отключения scroll

```
private void comboBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
 ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled=true;
}
```

Если хорошо подумать, можно додумать процедуру, которая будет переключать true/false по надобности